# Vscode cannot identify module.exports and export default {}

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have 2 js files in a folder. In  `js1` file i use `module.exports={something, nothing}` or `export default {something, nothing}`.
In another file `js2` i import like `import {something} from './js1'`.

Now when i cmd+click on `something` in `js2` file vscode does not takes me to its definition in `js1` file. But in webstorm it works out of the box.

How can i achieve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you would prefer to use `module.exports = {something, nothing}` in JS 1 and `const something = require('./js1').something` in JS 2

Provided `js1` and `js2` are in the same directory.

Comment: yeah ik but this convention is everywhere on codebase im working. So i cant change it.